# How can I make VS Code recognize ros2 python packages?

Tags: python, roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When working with python launch files, VS Code always complaints about  unresolved imports, such as  `unresolved import 'launch'` and `unresolved import 'launch_ros.actions'`. Of course, this also means I don't have access to IntelliSense.

How can I make VS Code recognize ros2 python packages?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/366598/how-can-i-make-vs-code-recognize-ros2-python-packages?/) by [tirafesi](https://answers.ros.org/users/64280/tirafesi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2020-11-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI,

The easiest way to work with VS Code is to use the [Visual Studio Code Extension for ROS](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-iot.vscode-ros)

If you have it installed,  just make sure you source the ROS setup (i.e. /opt/ros//setup.bash) or your workspace (install/setup.bash) before running VS code. It should recognize all the ROS components then,

---

Originally posted by [Mario Garzon](https://answers.ros.org/users/568/mario-garzon/) with karma: 802 on 2020-11-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RFRIEDM_Trimble](https://answers.ros.org/users/73619/rfriedm_trimble/) on 2021-04-22**:
If ROS2 is running in a Docker container, with VSCode using the remote containers extension, I cannot find a way to source ROS before VSCode opens. As a fix, I have installed the ROS extension.

- In .vscode/settings.json, add the
  following:

  - "ros.distro": "foxy"
- In .vscode/c_cpp_properties.json, add
  this to the includePath list:

  - "/opt/ros/foxy/include/**"

**Comment by [Mario Garzon](https://answers.ros.org/users/568/mario-garzon/) on 2021-04-26**:
If you are using Docker containers with VS Code, I'll definitely recommend you to check this:  [vscode-docker-ros2](https://allisonthackston.com/articles/vscode-docker-ros2.html)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could also add the path to your python folder in the settings.json file as follows:

```
"python.autoComplete.extraPaths": ["/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages"]
```

---

Originally posted by [wouterheerwegh](https://answers.ros.org/users/84316/wouterheerwegh/) with karma: 11 on 2021-09-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1